# Creating Sharepoint List field's using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have created a SharePoint `single line text` column and set its property `enforce unique value` to `true`.

The column has been created and its taking unique values only but when I go to column details page, there `enforce unique value` radio button is not checked?

[image]

Code:-

```
      string   fieldSchema = "<Field Type='" + field.FieldTypeKind + "' Indexed=\"TRUE\" DisplayName='" + field.Title + "' Name='" + field.InternalName + "' EnforceUniqueValues='" + field.EnforceUniqueValues + "' Hidden='" + field.Hidden + "' Required='" + field.Required + "'><Default>'" + field.DefaultValue + "'</Default></Field>";

targetcollField.AddFieldAsXml(fieldSchema, true, AddFieldOptions.AddToDefaultContentType);
                                    targetContext.Load(targetcollField);
                                    srcFieldCollections.Add(field);
```

Comment: So you are saying that Enforce unique Value you select as Yes while creating the column but later on when you go to column setting it is changed back to No.

Comment: can you paste your csom code in question..

Comment: I am creating field using CSOM, It's working as expected but in column setting it is not showing

Comment: EnforceUniqueValues="TRUE" first try with static value.

Comment: with static value also, same result